# express-session get all sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I use Node.js express and express-session

I want to get all session or find session by sessionID in express-session

- I had sessionID and want to find it
- I want to check if user still logged in by check expires time

Comment: If you want to know this in a request handler for the user making the request, then the express-session middleware will tell you in req.session if the session is still alive or not.

Comment: If you are outside of a request handler or want to look up another user, but have the sessionID, you can query the session store, using the `store.get()` method (whichever session store you are using).

Answer (score -1):

Please check below link

> > [link](https://npmjs.com/package/express-sessions)

express-sessions store your all session in mongodb ,

you can get your all sessions using below query

> > db.getCollection('sessions').find({})

and use bellow query for find by sessionID

> > db.getCollection('sessions').find({'sessionID':"Your SessionID"})